# Android Sqlite database crash while fetching and updating the value in the same function

Tags: java, android, kotlin, exception, android-sqlite

This is the function of android(Kotlin) app where sqlite database is used. My table name is `allcategories` and column's name is `clickcount` and I am facing an error as shown below:

```
 fun updateCountById(id: String?) {
        val mDataBase = this.writableDatabase
        val incrementQuery =
            "UPDATE allcategories SET clickcount = clickcount + 1 WHERE category = ?"
        val selectionArgs = arrayOf(id)
        Log.d("SQL Query", "Query: $incrementQuery, Args: ${selectionArgs.joinToString(", ")}")

        try {
            mDataBase.execSQL(incrementQuery, selectionArgs)
        } catch (e: SQLiteException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        val query = "SELECT clickcount FROM allcategories WHERE category = ?"
        val cursor = mDataBase.rawQuery(query, selectionArgs)
        var updatedCount = 0

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            val columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("clickcount")

            if (columnIndex != -1) {
                updatedCount = cursor.getInt(columnIndex)
            }
        }
        cursor.close()
        mDataBase.close()

        Log.e("Updated Count", "Updated the count for category $id to $updatedCount")
    }
```

The above is the function it is called when the button is clicked, this function fetches the current value of the count from db and increment it by 1 and again updates the incremented value to db

I am getting this below error:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException
> Exception android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException:
>
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement (SQLiteConnection.java:903)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare (SQLiteConnection.java:514)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare (SQLiteSession.java:588)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram. (SQLiteProgram.java:58)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery. (SQLiteQuery.java:37)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query (SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory (SQLiteDatabase.java:1408)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery (SQLiteDatabase.java:1347)
> at com.internetdesignzone.quotes.DatabaseHelper.getQuoteOfTheDay (DatabaseHelper.kt:214)
> at com.internetdesignzone.quotes.fragments.HomeFragment.onCreateView (HomeFragment.kt:349)
> at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView (Fragment.java:2995)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView (FragmentStateManager.java:523)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState (FragmentStateManager.java:261)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether (FragmentManager.java:1840)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute (FragmentManager.java:1764)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions (FragmentManager.java:1701)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange (FragmentManager.java:2849)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated (FragmentManager.java:2777)
> at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated (Fragment.java:3020)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView (FragmentStateManager.java:551)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState (FragmentStateManager.java:261)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState (FragmentStore.java:113)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1374)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange (FragmentManager.java:2841)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated (FragmentManager.java:2784)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated (FragmentController.java:262)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart (FragmentActivity.java:478)
> at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart (AppCompatActivity.java:210)
> at com.internetdesignzone.quotes.MainActivity.onStart (MainActivity.kt:235)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart (Instrumentation.java:1405)
> at android.app.Activity.performStart (Activity.java:8627)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity (ActivityThread.java:2991)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence (TransactionExecutor.java:180)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath (TransactionExecutor.java:165)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState (TransactionExecutor.java:142)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:70)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1830)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:193)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6914)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:592)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:858)

Comment: I believe that you need to concentrate on `at com.internetdesignzone.quotes.DatabaseHelper.getQuoteOfTheDay (DatabaseHelper.kt:214)` i.e. the exception appears to be when the `HomeFragment` is calling the `getQuoteOfTheDay` function.